# Colour coding comments in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I am a very visual person and would like a distinction between `#a command I commented out` and a `##message for myself or co-worker on the file`. I had a look around if RStudio supports different kinds of comments but it doesn't seem like it. Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: This wouldn't have anything to do with the R language. The color of a font in your code is controlled by the IDE or text editor you're using, such as RStudio, Eclipse, Notepad++, etc. Some, like Notepad++, allow you to edit and create color schemes such as what you're describing.

Comment: @Hack-R I can change the appearance such as font colour and size (I am using Rstudio), I am after a way I can distinguish different kinds of comments I leave in the code.

Comment: Many editors highlight comments starting with `TODO:` or `FIXME:` differently.

Comment: You can change the color of words in Microsoft Word or Open Office - if you wanted to know how to do that you would ask a question about MS Word or Open Office - it doesn't make the question about English. R is the language, RStudio (or Eclipse, Notepad++, Sublime Text, etc. etc.) are editors that let you display and edit R code and any other code. The coloring of your code has nothing to do with R and everything to do with your editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
#'* some colorful comment *
```

to comment in color.

-R version 3.6.3
-RStudio ‘1.2.5033 "Orange Blossom"

Comment: This is pretty cool. I see you can also do `#' @PurpleComment`

Answer (score 7):

```
#'[Red]

#'@Purple    

#'*Green*
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer to make it easier for others to understand.

Comment: @AlexH just try it in R-Studio

Answer (score 5):

As noted, this isn't an R question but an RStudio question (I've edited as such). RStudio doesn't currently have user-modifiable themes, just the built-in ones. That is apparently an in-development feature.

In the meantime, apparently you can hack away at the `.css` file that defines a theme to perhaps add what you're after - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200644098-appearance-Editor-theme

Otherwise, you could use a different editor that allows you to specify your desired syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, yes, I am after specific colour coding comments in RStudio. But not for the theme, the theme is fine. It is more that different kinds of comments can be colour coded.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is part of the theme.